# In Jenkins pipeline, what is the correct syntax to accept the passed-in parameter for this function?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a function that sets the NodeJS version.

```
def setNodeVersion(final String nodeVersion="11.15.0") {
  env.NODE_HOME = "${tool 'Node-"${nodeVersion}"'}"
  env.PATH="${env.NODE_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
  sh """
    node -v
    npm -v
  """
}

setNodeVersion("12.22.1")
```

But when I call it, I get

```
ERROR: No tool named Node-"${nodeVersion}" found
Finished: FAILURE
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set NODE_HOME, you're already inside a GString when invoking `tool`; no need for a second ${}.

Try `env.NODE_HOME = "${tool ('Node-' + nodeVersion)}"`.